# Symbol table in flex/bison

Tags: hash, hashtable, bison, flex-lexer, symbol-table

Does anyone know how to use the symbol table in Flex / Bison? I'm preparing a college exam but I can not understand the subject ...I've already tried searching on the internet but I find nothing that is well written.

Comment: Flex/bison do not implement a symbol table for you, which is probably why you have found little information. If you need a symbol table, you have to implement one yourself.

Comment: Yes, i know. I meant that I need to know if there is a structure or rules to follow when I implement it. what are the questions I need to ask myself when I'm creating a symbol table? @rici

Comment: The main question is "what do I need to know about each symbol?" There is really no other rule.